# webpack keeps asking , Which one do you like to install(webpack-cli/webpack-command)

Tags: node.js, webpack

I just installed Webpack, using: 
npm install -g webpack

I then run webpack from the command line without parameters:
webpack

Each time I do this.

```
One CLI for webpack must be installed. These are recommended choices, delivered as separate packages:
 - webpack-cli (https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli)
   The original webpack full-featured CLI.
 - webpack-command (https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-command)
   A lightweight, opinionated webpack CLI.
We will use "npm" to install the CLI via "npm install -D".
Which one do you like to install (webpack-cli/webpack-command):
```

Comment: did you install webpack-cli?

Comment: i didn't install webpack-cli @PlayMa256

Comment: you should install you, actually you MUST!

Comment: but i'm confuse which one install (webpack-cli / webpack-command)

Comment: any of then, pick one and install it.

Answer (score 2):

From webpack [v4.0.0-alpha.1](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6132) the cli component is moved to another independant package called `webpack-cli`

> - CLI has been move to webpack-cli, you need to install webpack-cli to
>     use the CLI

From [this github issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6157#issuecomment-353680368):

> it was intentional to make webpack-cli not a dependency of webpack:
>
> - Less depenencies when only using the node.js API
> - Both projects can develop indiviually.
> - Breaking changes for webpack-cli doesn't mean breaking change for webpack and in reverse.

So, you just to install `webpack-cli` one time and it will work as expected.

Note: You can also install `webpack-command`

Comment: i,m installing webpack-command throws Error: Cannot find moudle 'Webpack-command'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by installing an older version of the webpack:

```
npm uninstall -g webpack
npm install -g webpack@3
```

Answer (score 0):

For webpack 4 please use below command in the terminal:

```
npx webpack
```